# Using different symbols and colors for each row in a shapefile attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, symbology, display

I have a shapefile where I have a column of individual locations (ID field below), and then a column of yes/no data for each location. Some locations were visited twice and got different results.

I need to display this data so that each location is its own color, and where Yes locations are all triangles (regardless of color) and No locations are all circles.

Is this possible?

I tried it out using the Symbology - Multiple Attributes tool, it'll let me manually set colors for yes or no, but not unique symbols for different locations.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy/Paste your shapefile to the Data Frame/Table of Contents so you have two copies of the same shapefile:

[image]

Definition query one of the copies for Yes values, query the other for No values:

[image]

Then symbolize each by ID field:

[image]

The result should be something like this:

[image]

Just a disclaimer, this method is purely for display purposes.